To extort someone and extort someone out of something?
https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/missouri-woman-charged-alleged-scheme-steal-graceland-extort-elvis-pre-rcna166915 has the following title

Missouri woman charged in alleged scheme to steal Graceland and extort
Elvis Presley family

and sentence

A Missouri woman with a long history of small-time scams and fraud was
arrested Friday morning on federal charges in connection with a scheme
to extort Elvis Presley’s family out of millions and steal their
ownership interest in the music legend’s former Memphis home,
Graceland, prosecutors announced.

Is extorted used as to extort something out of someone?
Why is it used as to extort someone and to extort someone out of something?

You may find the following background of interest: https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/can-you-extort-a-person-new-usage

Sure, just like: to cheat someone out of something. BUT extort x for his money is better.

This is colloquial American English.

They extorted him out of millions.

The usage follows, by analogy, the pattern of

They cheated him out of millions.
They tricked him out of millions.
They swindled him out of millions.
They bamboozled him out of millions.

Someone might say:

They deceived him out of millions.
They seduced him out of millions.

This happens when, in the mind of the speaker, the abused verb has the requisite semantic overlap with the properly used verb(s).  Most of the time, the abused verb is from a "reading level" that is higher than the one the speaker normally spends their time in, or it comes from a domain that is not their usual bailiwick, and it will have a more specific definition and a different complement pattern than the verbs they're using as a template, so to speak.
out of conveys the sense of no longer having something that one formerly had. The extortionists tried to take from them what they had using extortion as the means.

The body text should use for and not out of:

... a scheme to extort Elvis Presley’s family for millions ...

M+W has a few examples on this use:

The attackers attempted to extort the district for millions of dollars ...


After being threatened with torture, their cellphones can be used to extort family members for thousands of dollars (which can often put them in severe debt).

Google Books has more examples.
Edit
Extort me for money has lots of hits.
Extort me out of money has just these few.

Given the way the internet works, I don't think you should include the original author's name with the revised version.

Thanks, @TimR.  I've deleted the names.

OR extort millions from EP's family.

Thanks, @Lambie.   Agreed.
